Is it okay to ask my advisor what he'll say in his letter of recommendation?
I'm applying to postdocs this fall. I'm not asking for a copy of the letter, but I would really like to know, generally, what the letter might look like and how positive it would be. I haven't been the best student (kind of late to publish, and I haven't been taking as much initiative as I think I should, considering my advisor is pretty hands-off).
Is it considered rude to ask my advisor something like "Would you be able to share what your recommendation might look like or how positive it would be?" It's not that I need this information, because I will ask him for a recommendation either way, but I would like to gauge my likelihood of getting a job offer.

I have always shared my letter with the postdocs. However, that always followed one or more strategy sessions with the postdoc. Where are they applying? What are the important criteria? What needs to be emphasized? How will the various letter writers address the important criteria and how can the emphasize it? Each job posting will be different, each application should be tailored to it, and ideally each letter is also tailored to the application. But, have the conversation(s) up front about what you think the letter should address and if the writer feels they can do that.

I don’t think it is standard practice sharing letters with students.

This question is similar to: How are Ph.D. applications evaluated in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students? Am I likely to get into school X?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ScottSeidman I'm applying to a postdoc. I pretty much understand the role of a letter of recommendation and the application process; this is more of an etiquette question.

ooops, wrong duplicate https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/47373/20457

This question is similar to: How do I effectively solicit a strong letter of recommendation from a professor?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@scientist - sure, it may not be standard practice, but after the strategy sessions and my commitment to write a letter in support then I see no harm in providing the text of the letter to the postdoc. You may choose differently.

@ScottSeidman and Sursula thanks! that will be helpful.

I agree with the strategy session suggested by Jon Custer. This could be helpful for both of you if you approach it right. I would open with something like "Would you feel comfortable writing a letter of recommendation for me?" If your advisor says yes, I would follow with, "Could we talk about my goals, my strengths and weaknesses, and I how I fit with this position?" This will naturally lead into how you can make the best case for your candidacy in your application. By the end of this conversation, your advisor will have a better idea of how he or she will approach the letter of recommendation, and you will have a sense of how strongly your advisor is likely support you, without having to ask to see the letter. Or you can say diplomatically, "Do you prefer that your letter be private?"

I have found that the following approach has served me well, initially as a student applying for scholarships, then as an undergraduate applying for graduate school and a PhD graduate applying for postdocs, and lastly as an academic applying for promotion ...
I ask a question along the following lines: "I'm considering applying for XYZ. Would you feel able to offer your enthusiastic support."
I've sometimes gotten responses (for job applications) like "Well, I've already told Dr B that I would support her application", or "I'm kind of snowed-under with exam marking at the moment", and other similar lukewarm responses  It might seem a little unusual, but I have never been misled into actually asking for a recommendation letter from anyone who was anything less than very positive about me. Another aspect of my approach that I think helps grease the social wheels is that the person I ask isn't embarrassed by potentially having to offer a direct rejection. This is important especially when I know that I might continue working for some time with the person I'm asking.

It is ok to ask, but you might take another avenue that would give you an idea about what it would contain. Instead of asking about a letter, ask about their view of you and advice for your future career. Ask about any issues they think you need to address to be successful.
There is risk in this, of course, if it gets them thinking about your shortcomings, so be sure to work towards leaving it on a positive note.
But just asking how strongly they would support you in faculty applications is ok, but caries risk itself, depending on personalities.

I think in normal circumstances advisors try their best to praise their students’ strengths and avoid talking about their weaknesses directly. They want to help students secure good jobs, because that will help attract new students and grant money for themselves. In many cases letter readers have to discount advisors’ positivity.
No student is perfect. There is no need to worry about what happened in the past. Just focus on your research as much as you can.
